# how to add many images to a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a form which is able to upload multiple selected files to the folder. I just need to find how how to insert them into the database using PHP?

HTML form

```
<form name="demoFiler" id="demoFiler" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="multiUpload" id="multiUpload" multiple />
<input type="submit" name="submitHandler" id="submitHandler" value="Upload" class="buttonUpload" />
</form>
```

PHP code

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'])){
        echo($_POST['index']);
    }
    exit;
}
```

---

This is my code and first of all I can't get the files to be moved to the upload folder:

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$host = "localhost";
$database = "db_holiday";

// Make the connect to MySQL or die
// and display an error.
$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select your database
mysql_select_db ($database);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
{
    foreach ($_FILES['multiUpload']['name'] as $fileName) { 
        $uploaddir= '/upload/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($fileName);
        if (move_uploaded_file($fileName, $uploadfile)) {
            echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        } else {
            echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
        }
    }
}

?>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="multiUpload[]" id="multiUpload" multiple="multiple" />
<input type="submit" name="button"/>
</form>
```

Comment: it depends on how you want to save the image?  Do you want to save it as a glob, the path to the file somewhere on the server, the image base64 encoded?  I would personally create a unique folder per each upload and associate the path with the image in the DB,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 `input type="file"` elements

```
<input type="file" name="img_1" />
<input type="file" name="img_2" />
```

Access each file using

```
$_FILES['img_1'][];
$_FILES['img_2'][];
```

Or you can also use an array like

```
<input type="file" name="img[]" />
<input type="file" name="img[]" />
<!--Which is often used in checkboxes-->
```

And access each image using

```
$_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][0];
$_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][1];
```

Comment: -1. Loops weren't mentioned in this answer, which are really a requirement when talking about **many** images.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt that's not understood? I mean we need to spoon feed now?

Comment: Spoon feeding is bad, I agree. However, *mentioning* loops doesn't immediately make it that. Judging by the question that was asked, this person doesn't have much experience with PHP yet, and he'll probably start writing code for indices 0 through X manually.

Comment: finally found the solution MYSELF guys.... i was just makin a simple mistake concerning the name of the file to be inserted in the database. finally its done ... thanks guys !! appreciated !!
P.S. apologies to those who thought i was tryin to get spoon fed !!

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="multiUpload[]" id="multiUpload" multiple />
```

php:

```
foreach ($_FILES['multiUpload'] as $fileName) { 
    //write your code here
    //$fileName
}
```